# File with com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I am not very familiar with Android but a friend of my friend said he made an app for my website on his computer. So he sent me the source file and I tried to rebuild the application but it doesn't work. I even tried to create a new project on my computer and copy/paste the code of each page. Then just change the project name but the problem is the same as below and I cant contact him again as he had done it just as a service for me. So I hope someone here can help me with this case because I have really become so tired of trying fix this issue.

Error message is:

```
Maven package paths must start with m2repository
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:117)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallSelectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger.logError(InstallSelectedPackagesStep.java:403)
    at com.android.sdklib.repositoryv2.MavenInstaller.install(MavenInstaller.java:102)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallSelectedPackagesStep$InstallTask.run(InstallSelectedPackagesStep.java:242)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.berava"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v2.1.0'
}
```

---

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating packages via SDK Manager, like Google Repository, Support Library, etc. ConstraintLayout is available in the Canary/preview channel.

Comment: I tried and i face error where i post in my post (post updated)

Comment: Can you add the contents of the build.gradle file?

Comment: which one you mean: build.gradle (project: Berava)
build.gradle (module: app)

Comment: Can you post both? There might be typo in the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` 1.0.0-alpha2 is bundled only with Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2. So you have to install the preview from http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest

Answer (score 4):

change 1.0.0-alpha2 to alpha1 and it should work. I think alpha2 works only with Android Studio preview 2, after that it is changed to alpha1.

Comment: Changing to alpha1 fixed mine :) Showing me that alpha1 is obsolete though .... :/

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager and then go to SDK tools as shown in image below and check the required constraint layout which in your case will be `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha2`

[image]